# Hover delay for parent of Dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown menu. This code for it is:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.has-sub').hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("tap", 350, "easeOutSine");
    });
  });
</script>

<li class="has-sub">
  <a href="briefing.html">
    <img src=images/plane.png id=menu-icons>Flight Briefing<span class="sb-arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="flightlog.html">
        <img src="images/share.png" id="menu-icons">Flight Log</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="loadsheet.html">
        <img src="images/weight.png" id="menu-icons">Loadsheet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/compass.png" id="menu-icons">Alternates</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/listing-option.png" id="menu-icons">Operational Flightplan</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

What I trying to do is to create a hover delay for parent of the Dropdown. You would need to hover over "Flight Briefing" for 2 seconds for the Dropdown menu to appear.

I have tried some other solutions that were provided with different questions, but they did not work.

Comment: Why didn't you mark my answer as the best one? The other one didn't even work...

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .hover() function is a little wrong - you need a mouseenter and mouseleave function - I have set a timer of 2000 ms (2s) by using setTimeout() to give the 2 sec delay (although in my opinion thats a really long time to hover on an element beforehte effect occurs) and have the mouseout hide the ul directly. I am showing the ul buy habing the .has-sub ul have a display:none and then by adding the .tap class- display:block.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.has-sub').hover(
      function(){setTimeout(function(){$('.has-sub').addClass("tap")},2000)},
      function(){$(this).removeClass("tap"); clearTimeout()}
      );
  });
```

```css
.has-sub ul{display:none}
.tap ul{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-sub">
  <a href="briefing.html">
    <img src=images/plane.png id=menu-icons>Flight Briefing<span class="sb-arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="flightlog.html">
        <img src="images/share.png" id="menu-icons">Flight Log</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="loadsheet.html">
        <img src="images/weight.png" id="menu-icons">Loadsheet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/compass.png" id="menu-icons">Alternates</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/listing-option.png" id="menu-icons">Operational Flightplan</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The dropdown appears even if the user hovers it for 10ms.

Comment: thanks @Kind user - answer amended to clear the timeout

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. If you need anything else, let me know.

```js
$('.link').mouseenter(function(){
  int = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.dropdown').fadeIn();
  }, 2000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
  clearTimeout(int);
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="has-sub">
  <a href="briefing.html" class='link'>
    <img src=images/plane.png id=menu-icons>Flight Briefing<span class="sb-arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class='dropdown'>
    <li>
      <a href="flightlog.html">
        <img src="images/share.png" id="menu-icons">Flight Log</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="loadsheet.html">
        <img src="images/weight.png" id="menu-icons">Loadsheet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/compass.png" id="menu-icons">Alternates</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/listing-option.png" id="menu-icons">Operational Flightplan</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to hide the ul on mouse out

Comment: @gavgrif OP didn't even mentioned it.